# Terminology for a function that returns the same value when applied more than once

Tags: functions

Is there a widely-used terminology that classifies a function $f$ that exhibits the following behavior:

$f(x)=f(f(x))$

Like "reentrant function" or "distilling function"?

Comment: Such functions are called [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation)

Comment: @lulu you want to answer the question, then I'll accept it?

Comment: Actually, I tried to post this as an answer but the system automatically transferred it to a comment, claiming it was "a trivial answer".   Ironically, I agree with that though in the past I've had criticism for posting solutions as comments, as here.  In any case, the posted solution from @Magma is essentially equivalent so you can accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a function $f$ with $f(f(x)) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in its domain is called a [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(mathematics)) in general usage.

It can also be called [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) with regards to function composition: $f \circ f = f$.

The term *projection* is preferred when the map involved is geometrically motivated, or uniquely determined in some sense, and the term *idempotent* is preferred when the composition operator is in focus in some way.